# Core Plot -[UIView setHostedGraph:]: unrecognized selector

Tags: iphone, sdk, core-plot

I have fixed my big Core Plot problem after hours of research and trial and error.
And have bumped into another issue.
I thought the one I fixed would be the final one.
But no, another one.
Anyway, here is todays issue:-[UIView setHostedGraph:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa524970

Im assuming it has something to do with this:   hostingView.hostedGraph = barChart; .
Please help me solve it.
It would really **really** **really** **really** mean allot to me if some one could help me out.
http://pastebin.com/dqXbjWNv
Is the code that I'm having trouble with.

Comment: This is a double release problem. Enable Zombies in the Xcode scheme editor, or just search google for "Xcode NSZombiesEnabled"

Answer (score 2):

That error means that your `hostingView` is a `UIView`, not a `CPTGraphHostingView`. Make sure to change the class name in Interface Builder.

Comment: Well, I have changed the interface from

interface CPTTestGraphHostingView : UIViewController <SomeProtocalIcannotRemmeber>{ } To interface CPPTTestGraphHostingView : CPTGraphHosting view. Now I get this error: request for member 'view' in something not a structure or union

Comment: You need a view in your UI and a view controller to control it. Change the class of the `UIView` to `CPTGraphHostingView` in Interface Builder. Your original view controller declaration was correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CPTGraphHostingView and still get this error it might be related to the linker flag,

set  **-ObjC -all_load**
in other linker flags in build settings

[image]